# When i get the latest project from tfs and try ti build it this error came "csc.exe" exited with code - 2146232576"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Everytime I try to rebuild or build my code, 
I am having this error that "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232576 , 
I cleaned my solution and restarted Visual Studio with no gain. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did u try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034352/visual-studio-build-error-csc-exe-exited-with-code-532462766

Comment: @sriharsha  Yes already tried ,still giving the same issue

Comment: @ankit try cleaning solution

Answer (score 0):

A question on this error was answered by [Cole Wu on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99897aee-fbc0-4b04-afee-4d2d0507680e/quotcscexequot-exited-with-code-2146232576-when-trying-to-run-application?forum=msbuild) suggesting using the Package Manager Console (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console) and enter:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 1.3.2
```

Otherwise there's another question asking about the same error code on SO here [IIS Compilation Error -2146232576 AspNetInitializationExceptionModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892851/iis-compilation-error-2146232576-aspnetinitializationexceptionmodule)
 that might help.